# How to redirect old permalinks from https://exmaple.com/category/post_id to https://exmaple.com/category/post_id.html

Tags: permalinks, redirect, urls

How to redirect old permalinks from  https://exmaple.com/category/post_id to https://exmaple.com/category/post_id.html

Comment: exmaple, really?

Comment: you want to redirect to .html? what have you tried that didn't work?